# printing a list inside a triple quote

Tags: python

I would like to print elements of a list inside an email message.

I defined my list in my python script like:

```
exceptions = []
```

At the end of the script the list will have the following elements:

```
This is a boy.
This is a girl.
This is a dog.
```

I would like to print the elements of the list called 'exceptions' inside an email that is contrived in the python script.

```
fromaddr = 'xxx@xxx.com'
toaddrs  = 'xxx@xxx.com'

msg = """Subject:Big Bro FTP issue.
From: xxx@xxx.com
To:  xxx@xxx.com

!!!PRINT THE EXCEPTION LIST HERE!!!
"""
print "Message length is " + repr(len(msg))


smtp_server = 'xxxxx.com'
smtp_username = 'xxxxxx'
smtp_password = 'xxxxxx'
smtp_port = '587'
smtp_do_tls = True

server = smtplib.SMTP(
host = smtp_server,
port = smtp_port,
timeout = 10
)

server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
print server.quit()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

i would prefer `MIMEText`

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEText
msg = MIMEText("your_maeeage")
msg['From'] = <sender-email>
msg['To'] = <reciver-email>
msg['Subject'] = "your_subject"
server = smtplib.SMTP(<server>,<port>)
server.starttls()
server.login(Username,password)
server.sendmail(from_addr,to_addr,msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 1):

[Format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is a nice method to know which allows you to put place holders in a list. Of course, here you could simple append to the list, but it's useful. Use [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to format the list of strings into a single string, here separated by a new line (`\n`).

```
msg = """Subject:Big Bro FTP issue.
From: xxx@xxx.com
To:  xxx@xxx.com

{}
""".format('\n'.join(exceptions))
```

or:

```
msg = """Subject:Big Bro FTP issue.
    From: xxx@xxx.com
    To:  xxx@xxx.com
""" + '\n'.join(exceptions)
```

Comment: `exceptions` is already an iterable that can be passed directly to `join`. You don't need an additional generator `ex for ex in exceptions`. (This actually slows `join` down, because it builds a list from from the input anyway.)

Comment: @chepner true, missed that. Thanks. I'm used to using join a certain way :/